# QML ToolButton background colour

Tags: qt, background, qml, border

I have the following QML:

```
    ToolButton {
        id: frameCapButton
        height: mainWindow.iconHeight
        width: height

        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 2
            border.width: (imageCaptureModel.imageType == ImageCaptureModel.ImageTypeFrame) ? 2 : 0
            border.color: (imageCaptureModel.imageType == ImageCaptureModel.ImageTypeFrame) ? "#ff0000" : "transparent"
        }
        contentItem: ColoredImage {
            source: "ImageViewer/framecapture.svg"                            
            color: Colours.buhlerGreen()
        }
        onClicked: {
            imageCaptureModel.imageType = ImageCaptureModel.ImageTypeFrame
            placeHolder = frameText
            pixelField.text = ""
        }
    }
```

I added the block "background" and it gives the entire button a white background, why?  How do I keep the border and loose the white background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `color` property in QML can be fed with `QColor` or a string (or bound to another property of course) see [Qt Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-color.html).

In this case you are feeding it with a property called `transparent`, however QML cannot find it:

```
qrc:/main.qml:23: ReferenceError: transparent is not defined
```

When you try the following you will have a transparent background:

```
color: "transparent"
```